# Aligning form fields for responsive layout

Tags: html, css, forms, responsive-design

Im currently trying to fix a form that i have built to work on a responsive layout

Ive attached a jpeg of what the form should look like a on full version of the site with the comments field aligned to the right of the rest of fields but when viewed on a mobile i want the comments field to drop below the rest of the fields.

Because i was advised to wrap the comments field in a DIV and place it before the rest of the form fields then float it right, when i view the mobile version the comments field sits at the top of the form instead of the bottom

any suggestions to how i can fix this issue?

see the CSS & HTML below

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color: #FFF;
}

#form {
width:960px;
background-color:#edf8ff;
 height:650px;
}

.gezza-form {
width:894px;
margin:0 auto;
margin-top:20px;
}

.gezza-field {
width:437px;
height:75px;
margin-bottom:10px;
border: 1px solid #d9e7f1;
}

.gezza-comments{
width:437px;
height:300px;
}

-->
</style></head>

<body>


<div id="form">

<form action="" class="gezza-form" method="post" >
<div style="float:right;">Comments<br /><textarea name="comments" cols="" rows="" class="gezza-comments" ></textarea></div>
First Name<br />
<input name="firstname" type="text" class="gezza-field" /><br/>
Last Name<br />
<input name="lastname" type="text" class="gezza-field" /><br/>
Email Address<br />
<input name="email" type="text" class="gezza-field" />

</form>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, you have not attached any jpeg.

Comment: image attached now, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Should all fields have a fixed width? Wrap each column in a `div`, then float both divs left and give them an explicit width.

Answer (score 0):

Put the div with the text area below the other fields in the HTML.

That should get you a lot closer.

Then, you will need to wrap each field / label pair in a div too.

On the mobile view it should all go into place more or less (bit of padding / margin needed maybe).

Then, on the wider view float the div for the text area right and the other fields' divs left.  You'll need to set width for them .. say 49% each.

You'll need to use a clear fix on the element after this lot to clear the floats.